# Show previous month's posts

Tags: query-posts, date

I've managed to loop through the current month's posts in January but I am trying to get the previous month's posts in December of the previous year. I think this is where the problem might be, that it is 2014 and the the posts I am after is in 2013 (Dec). I'd appreciate it if someone can spot the problem. I have been through hordes of examples, the codex and the WordPress forums but not found anything that would work.

```
        <!-- PREVIOUS MONTH NEWS  -->

        <?php 

            $prevMonth = date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 0, date('Y')));                                               

            $newsPrevArgs = array(
                'cat'               => 'news',
                'monthnum'          => $prevMonth,
                'order'             => 'DES',
                'posts_per_page'    => 5
            );
        ?>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <h3 class="news-previous-month"><?php echo date('M Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 0, date('Y'))) ?></h3>

        <?php 

            $previous_news = new WP_Query( $newsPrevArgs );
            $isFirstNewsLoop = true;
            $newsItemNum = 0;

            // Loop through all news items

            while ( $previous_news->have_posts() ) {
                $previous_news->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php 
                        echo '<div class="news-article news-article-' . $newsItemNum . ' ' . ( $isFirstNewsLoop ? 'news-article-current' : '') . '">';


                            echo '<span class="news-date">' . get_the_date('d M Y', '<strong>', '</strong>') . '</span>';
                            echo '<span class="news-thumb">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'home-widget-210') . '</span>';
                            echo '<span class="news-title"><strong>' . get_the_title() . '</strong></span>';
                            echo '<span class="news-blurb">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</span>';
                            wp_reset_postdata();
                        echo '</div>'
                    ?>


                <?php

                    $newsItemNum +=1;
                    $isFirstNewsLoop = false;


                ?>

        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a simple PHP issue of how you are asking to return the first date()

```
date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 0, date('Y')));
```

is returning Dec, and WP_Query needs the month number.  First, try changing 'M' to 'm'.

```
date('m', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 0, date('Y')));
```

If that doesn't work, try using the [date_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) and pass the year in as well.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use year in conjunction of monthnum.

```
// Calculate month or year based on your WordPress timezone setting
// As post date is based on the timezone you set on general setting page on wp-admin
$current_month_num = date('m', current_time('timestamp') );
$current_month_year = date('Y', current_time('timestamp') );

// if current month number is less that 2, what's probably 1|January
// then the last month will be 12|December
// and year will be last year
if( $current_month_num < 2 )
{
    $prev_month_num = 12;
    $prev_month_year = $current_month_year - 1;
}
// if month number is not less that 2, then previous month will be from current year
else
{
    $prev_month_num = $current_month_num - 1;
    $prev_month_year = $current_month_year;
}

// The query argument
$newsPrevArgs = array(
    'cat'               => 'news',
    'year'              => $prev_month_year,
    'monthnum'          => $prev_month_num,
    'order'             => 'DES',
    'posts_per_page'    => 5
);
```